# When publishing how to have only the latest version

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have a WPF application which i publish in intranet, the thing is i published the application 20 times till now, so i have 20 folders and the size of the build becomes more, i manually delete and leave only 2 latest versions, but is there a way to only have latest version to be published?

Right now i save in folder and then copy to `inetpub\wwwroot`, but if i had to send the files directly using Visual Studio, i have speed issues due to weak intranet lines in some branches.

[image]

Comment: What is the tool or process that is creating the versioned folders?

Comment: I just do build and publish in visual studio 2017 for window based WPF application ,i dont know the process ,can you please give an example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when u publish only current and previous version source are there in application files,Visual studio publishing tool doesnt  delete the older versions in published folder ,so we are seeing too many folders .Just delete everything in publish folder before publsihing and you will have only two folders current and previous version.

Answer (score 0):

> but is there a way to only have latest version to be published?

You *are* already only publishing the latest version each time you publish.

The older versions don't magically disappear when you publish a new version though. You'll have to remove them manually one way or another:

[Can ClickOnce be configured to delete off old published directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834792/can-clickonce-be-configured-to-delete-off-old-published-directories)